# How to calculate spent hours from same dates

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table `tbl_employees_attendance` that has column `in_time` and `out_time` with `employee_id` when I run query for find attendance.

```
$curr_date = '';
foreach($atts AS $row) {
    $in_time_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row->in_time));
    if($curr_date != $in_time_date){
        $spend_time = strtotime($row->out_time) - strtotime($row->in_time);
        $curr_date = $in_time_date;          
    }else{
        $spend_time += strtotime($row->out_time) - strtotime($row->in_time);
    }
}
```

The returned result look like **this**:

```
+========================================+
|    out_time      |     in_time         |
+========================================+
2019-11-11 18:00:00 - 2019-11-11 09:00:00
2019-11-12 10:00:00 - 2019-11-12 09:00:00
2019-11-12 15:00:00 - 2019-11-12 13:00:00
2019-11-13 18:00:00 - 2019-11-13 09:00:00
2019-11-13 20:00:00 - 2019-11-13 18:00:00
2019-11-14 18:00:00 - 2019-11-14 09:00:00
+========================================+
```

In attendance list have multiple same dates, now I won't get total spend hours by group dates look like **this**:

```
2019-11-11  =>  09:00:00
2019-11-12  =>  03:00:00
2019-11-13  =>  10:00:00
2019-11-14  =>  9:00:00
```

Comment: The problem is when loop is run date is not grouped correctly.

Comment: Can you please provide a `var_export` of $atts, so that we can easily test this?

Comment: Yes, what is the issue in this code, on top I show foreach loop and then showing loop return result, after that I show what I want.

Comment: $atts is variable of select query. like `$atts = select * from tbl_employees_attendance where employee_id = 103 `

Comment: That doesn’t help us in testing this though, we don’t have your database available.

Comment: database have just three columns `employee_id, in_time,out_time` if you want I show database table structure, tell me I can show it.

Comment: No, I just want you to provide an [mre] so that we can easily test your code. Provide an array with the values, and add the parts where you actually create the output to the loop you have shown.